# oracle forms 12c can I get application on internet like web no client installation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracleforms

Dear all can I get oracle 12C application access as web on internet I know this process will not as all can be explained here but someone please guide me in which way I have to go lead me how can I get this goal some hints or topic books or article I searched lot of internet but wont get this.

Comment: Are you talking about *building* a Forms application? For that, you need the software\

Answer (score 1):

My last Forms version is 10g; it uses the IAS (Internet Application Server), while your version (12c) uses the WLS (Weblogic Server). However, I believe that my answer  still stands.

In order to run a Forms application, you have to have a database (of course) and a "server" which will be running that application. I'm just a developer so I never had to install nor configure the IAS (or the WLS). However, based on what I've heard from colleagues and read on the Internet, that is not a simple task, requires a lot of knowledge and takes time to do it. Measures in *days*.

Shortly, you should

- install the database (on a database server)
- install the WLS (on a separate application server, for better performance)
- make everything accessible to users over the Internet
- share the application URL with users

Reading your question & from my point of view, your best option is to find a company that hosts Forms applications, sign the contract with them and let them take care about deploying your application to the web. Your task would remain what it is now - *developing* the application.